# Streaming audio from smartphone to PC without bluetooth

Tags: streaming, speaker

How should I do this if I wanted to stream Spotify using my smartphone but the audio comes from the speakers connected to my PC? I only have USB speakers that can't be connected to my smartphone using the 3.5 mm jack.

Answer (score 1):

My first question would be: why not just stream Spotify right on the PC? You can stream right in a web browser or install the desktop app.

Second question: Could you please clarify your device and your PC?

Comment: Streaming or browsing directly could be blocked if it's at work, so it would be impossible to either stream or even download things. The PC probably lacks Bluetooth adapter too as many working PCs do.

Comment: @deags - Good points, but don't give up because of corporate blocks. For a long time, my company blocked Spotify so we couldn't use the desktop app or Spotify site via browser to stream... until I installed a VPN Proxy browser extension (like HOX) and then I could stream Spotify (and Pandora) in-browser while connected to the corporate network.
Granted, there are all types of corporate blocks, so installing browser extensions isn't always possible. You don't know until you try.

Comment: Fair point, but I can still think of a few more scenarios where you want to stream audio from phone: 1-Legally being unable to install stuff yourself on the work PC, there being no internet at all (rare but still possible). 2-The PC has no internet connection. 3-You want to listen to your mp3s (not Spotify though). 4- Someone's calling and you need everyone to listen but the phones speaker's are bad... but you have your computer there with slightly better audio or with recording software.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your device android device and PC with [Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender) (app) and enjoy your phone as audio streaming server.