# Redirecting phone's audio to pc through usb

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-note-4

So I want to basically redirect my phone's audio to my computer's playback device through USB and not through Bluetooth which is what most posts are seemingly concerned with.

---

This guy [Streaming audio from smartphone to PC without bluetooth](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/streaming-audio-from-smartphone-to-pc-without-bluetooth) asked a similar question about 2 years ago which hasn't really been answered so far so I thought I would bring it up again.

---

Devices and Os's :

Phone : Samsung Galaxy note 4 under Android 6.0.1
Pc : Windows 10 pro

Comment: Basically it's not an Android question, but a PC question: All you have to do is make your PC advertise itself as audio device. Then pair it and play! I had done that with Linux a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

Download third party software **Wondershare MirroGo**. It works great (Not promoting).
**This works only for screen rendering and audio can only be heard in recordings. No direct audio routing.**
Some instructions to follow:-
 - You can download Mirror Go from [Here](https://drfone.wondershare.com/android-mirror.html)
 - After downloading and installing, Enable your phone's USB
    debugging, see here -  [How to enable USB Debugging.](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm)
 - Simply connect your phone with USB and accept the [adb authorization
    request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPh73.png) pop-ups on screen and you're done.
Main advantages of this software is that:
 - You can render your phone's screen on Desktop/Laptop.
 - You can play games/movies/songs through MirrorGo.
 - You can control your phone via MirrorGo through Mouse/Keyboard.
 - You can record your screen via MirrorGo during the live view of your phone in your laptop/desktop.
You can Also use MirroGo with MobileGO ( an advanced software to backup your whole phone with one click and tons of features and works for Iphone too).

**UPDATED:** - (With audio/Video/Images support)
 Here's a solution using all time favorite media player VLC.
It doesn't work with USB (sorry for this) but It works great with a local network. 
you can either create hotspot of your phone and connnect your lap/desk with it or you can connect both the devices to a same network.
It's the best fluent method out there and It works for Audio/Video/Images.
So here's the method:

- Download [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwawM4Wx7rKnSGl0Z0E3NEsyUFk) apk in your phone and install it. I have decompiled it
  without ads for easy use.
- Connect your pc and phone with the same network or connect your pc to
  your phone's hotspot.
- Download [this](http://104.196.41.0:23456/download/VLCDIRECT.BAT) VLCdirect.bat file and Run it as Administrator.
- Write click VLC, select properties and in target paste this `--http-password=vlcdirect`
  after the location which is like this
  `"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"`
  .
  Note that there's a space between " and --.
- Open VLC and enable Web interface, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wma7r.jpg) image.
- Open the app and click done and skip everything as you would be done
  with all those steps if you're on this step.

  Now you're all set. Play anything through the app and you'll see it in PC's VLC without buffering. It really works fast.
  **Two points to note:**
- Usually .bat files contain the virus but it's secure. you can verify
  it by right-clicking the .bat file and click on edit and see
  yourself.
- You don't have to do all this everytime. Just click on Web interface
  in pc's VLC.

Comment: I have tried the application you recommended, it is indeed very nice and works great for the screen rendering. Though, i cannot seem to make the sound part work, it plays audio on the phone by default and i see no parameter in the computer app to change that.

Comment: Sorry for this, It works only in the recording. Updating the answer with another solution.

Comment: So i set up vlc and vlc direct as you recommended, it works great once again and the responsiveness is impressive i will most certainly use this conjunction with MirrorGo and thank you for telling me about both of those. Though, my main problem remain unsolved, I wanted to *redirect* my phone's audio, and by that i mean that i wanted to be able to do anything on my phone (like passing phonecalls, watching a youtube video, use a newly install radio app) and be able to hear it as i would with the phone's speaker but through my computer's headset.

Comment: I realize that what I am trying to achieve may be borderline impossible and you were of a huge help regardless, thank you for your time.

Comment: (sorry for the poor English in the long comment it seems that i ran out of edits to correct the mistakes)

Comment: And about the Bluetooth part,  I mainly requested a non Bluetooth solution because my desktop computer doesn't support Bluetooth and buying a dongle or a new network adapter is really possible right now.

Comment: No problem mate and Language doesn't matter, you don't have to be sorry or say sorry for that.  At least I helped you a bit, that's enough. And yeah, your main requirement is still incomplete.